# how to create multiple array in one foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is it possible to have one foreach loop in PHP with multiple array?

im create this code but not working

`<?php foreach ($data as $value) && ($data1 as $value1) { ?>`

Comment: no, use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: create foreach loop for array having more element and use second array inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
foreach (array_combine($data, $data1) as $value => $value1)
```

Insted of

```
<?php foreach ($data as $value) && ($data1 as $value1) { ?>
```

**OR Another Solution is**

```
foreach($courses as $course)
{
    foreach($sections as $section)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_combine` will only work if both array have same number of elements.

Comment: you can test first if both array have same value or not if not you can add blank value in array.

Comment: Your another solution is wrong ,Code wise. it will run  n*n times

Answer (score 0):

$data is array, having more or even elements than $data1

```
 $i = 0;
 $keys = array_keys($data1);

 foreach($data as $value){
   $value1 = $data1[$keys[$i]];
   $i++;
 }
```

Just like @Confused suggested.